# iPhoto not launching after upgrade to Yosemite, I don't know how to execute the fix

Tags: macos, photos.app, migration

I migrated a MacBook pro to a new iMac with Yosemite.  I then upgraded iPhoto to v 9.6, and when I try to launch iPhoto, it does not launch, stating: iPhoto cannot be opened because of a problem.

I found the fix to the problem on a related question on this site that references: http://www.sanebutdifferent.com/iphoto-11-nyxaudioanalysis-crash-error

This appears to address my issue, based on the error report.  I've downloaded the replacement file, but I don't know where to put it.  I don't seem to have a /library folder. Where should I be looking?  Finder will not let me create a /library folder either.

Comment: Every Mac has two common Library folders.  The one mentioned in the post of your link is directly on your boot volume (by default, it is named "Macintosh HD").  To find it fairly easy, in Finder click the menu "Go", then select "Computer".  There, choose "Macintosh HD" and then Library.  In case you renamed "Macintosh HD", you need to substitute that, of course. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether that is a true fix or not - however, that file doesn't actually reside in /Library/Frameworks/ it is symlinked from `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NyxAudioAnalysis.framework`
to
`/Library/Frameworks/NyxAudioAnalysis.framework`

You would need to replace the original, not the symlink

---

The simplest way to get there is…

- switch to Finder
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>   for new window
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>  for Go to…
- Copy/paste `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/`
- Hit Enter
- drag the file in [you might want to copy the original to the desktop first, just in case]
- click 'replace'

Comment: couple of edits - make sure you're looking at the latest version of my post - apologies.

Comment: I replaced in both places and iPhoto now works. Thanks.

Comment: ach - I wouldn't replace both - the symlink may be used by another app/service & any update that replaces the original would not necessarily replace the link. I'd have a look at something like https://gigaom.com/2011/04/27/how-to-create-and-use-symlinks-on-a-mac/ on how to replace it - it would be safer overall. … though I'm glad it did work for you ;)